# ¿Como hago para que mi archivo que se descargue en excel no salga dañado?, pq cuando lo abro si se creo todos los elementos correctamente

Tags: javascript, html

este es mi codigo, quiero convertir mis tablas a excel pero me sale archivo dañado, quiero que no me salga el mensaje del archivo dañado

```javascript
// Código de la función tableToExcel
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,';
  var template = '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>';
  var base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))); };
  var format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }); };
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table);
    var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML };
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
    link.download = name ? (name + '.xls') : 'exported_table.xls';
    link.click();
  };
})();
```

Comment: Prueba con `link.download = name ? (name + '.xlsx') : 'exported_table.xlsx';`